# creating json payload from dataframe pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, aws-glue

I have a requirement to create json payload for each row in a dataframe. It isnt just simple mapping , some attributes have logic applied to them and some others have to be looked up from another table which is in another dataframe. after creating the json payload , need to call an external api.
Currently I'm using df.collect() method to loop through each element and craft the payload for each of them. For running this in a very large dataset(10gb) , I'm afraid this might be slow , or crash. Is there any efficient way in pyspark or in aws glue?

Comment: Why not just write it as json and read it using jsonlines package line by line ?
You can also, switch to rdd and do a map or mapParition on each chunk

Comment: Hi, I have tried like you said but I am getting error for some attributes which require to search on another lookup table, I'm using df.filter to search on them but getting error saying cannot pickle R_THREADLOCK